# Bean Creation Exception after Upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.2 from 2.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I recently upgraded my application from Spring Boot 2.x to Spring Boot 3.2.2. After the upgrade, my application fails to start, and when I enabled debug logging, I noticed the following error messages are being printed repeatedly in a loop:

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck:1011 -  Bean creation exception on singleton FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration': No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
2024-03-25 23:47:30.937  DEBUG [main] mdc:{} DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:225 -  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration'
```

I have not encountered this issue with Spring Boot 2.x. Here are the steps I have taken to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Ensured all dependencies are compatible with Spring Boot 3.2.2.
2. Checked for any deprecated configurations or classes.
3. Enabled debug logging to pinpoint the issue.

However, the error persists, and the application fails to launch. It seems like there's an issue with bean creation, specifically related to RetryConfiguration. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: could you provide some code to get to know what your doing?

Comment: fixed it there was a WARN level log which prints  ```2024-03-27 19:33:43.593 WARN  [main] mdc:{} AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.refresh:632 -  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:... ...'org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisIndexedSessionRepository' ...Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}```